# Invoke method only when other method are done - RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have 2 method:

```
private void method1() throws InterruptedException {
        //SimulateLongOperation
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("hello1");
    }

private void method2(){
        System.out.println("hello2");
    }
```

I would like to invoke method2 when method1 is done, but I don't want to block UI thread.
Is it possible to do it with RxJava ?
How will it look like? There are no simple examples on the internet, there are only great articles that I can not understand.

When I invoke:

```
method1();  
method2();
```

I block the main thread, it's horrible.

Answer (score 2):

You also could try the following:

- With Kotlin:

```
     Completable.fromAction{ method1() }
            .doOnComplete{ method2() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe()
```

- With Java:

```
     Completable.fromAction(() -> method1() )
            .doOnComplete(__ ->  method2())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a really specific answer I will post a naive implementation here. Depending on your usecase there maybe better solutions.

```
    private void method1() throws InterruptedException {
            //SimulateLongOperation
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("hello1");
        }

    private void method2(){
            System.out.println("hello2");
        }

    void solution() {
      Observable<Void> first = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                method1();
                return null;
            });
    Observable<Void> second = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                method2();
                return null;
            });
    first.flatMap((Function<Void, ObservableSource<?>>) aVoid -> second)
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe();
    }
```

Comment: this rxjava method looks very unreadable. Is there a simpler code ?

Comment: This is the simplest I could come with. If you could point out which part seems complicated, I can try to explain and make it simpler to understand.

Comment: I can't invoke "fromCallable" on Observable

Comment: are you using RxJava 1 or 2? This code is valid for RxJava 2. Please add the following lines to your build.gradle

   `implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'`